# How to check if getResources is null without getting ResourcesNotFound

Tags: android, null

I have a number of sounds organized in levels, level1explicacio2, level2explicacio8, etc. Sometimes this sound will exist sometimes not. So I need to check if for example level5explicacio3 exist, and if it does, play some animation. So I made a if check if levelSoundPlayer is null, but of course, it doesn't compile because it cannot find a resource for levelSoundPlayer. How can I sort this out?

```
        levelSound = "level" + sharedPreferences.getString("Level","1") + "explicacio" + Integer.toString(1);


    Log.i("aviam", levelSound);
    levelSoundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(levelSound, "raw", getPackageName()));
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageViewReplace = findViewById(R.id.imageViewReplace);

    if (levelSoundPlayer!=null){
        Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f);
        a.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        a.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        a.setDuration(1000);
        imageViewReplace.startAnimation(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check it from their Identifier, like below

```
levelSound = "level" + sharedPreferences.getString("Level","1") + "explicacio" + Integer.toString(1);
        Log.i("aviam", levelSound);
        levelSoundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(levelSound, "raw", getPackageName()));
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageViewReplace = findViewById(R.id.imageViewReplace);

        int valId = getResources().getIdentifier(levelSound, "raw", getPackageName());
        if (valId != 0){
            Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f);
            a.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            a.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            a.setDuration(1000);
            imageViewReplace.startAnimation(a);
        }
```

In [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources](http://this) documentation also said

> int The associated resource identifier. Returns 0 if no such resource
>   was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)